# Can I use paypal for android app which charges for video upload service

Tags: android, paypal

As stated on [Android Developer Policy](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)  for

> In-app purchases: Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within an application downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's payment system as the method of payment, except:
>
> where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g. buying movie tickets; e.g. buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or
>
> where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g. buying songs that can be played on other music players)

does the following app fall under `except` clause  or `services` mentioned above

Video Upload App

1. User records video
2. Before uploading the video to the server,user must do some payment using paypal
3. For that I am planning to use `PayPal` libraries.

   The concept behind this app is similar to `Audition` fees that may or may not include on `Reality Shows`  like `American Idol`.So the user in order to submit his/her `audition video` recorded by his/her mobile phone, he/she must pay some fees via `Paypal`.So,does this fall under `payment for services` or not.Meaning, can I use `Paypal` or I have to opt for `Google checkout`.Lastly,I need to  release this app on `Play Store`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use googles billing as they not taking anything away from the app for the payment.

For example if a user was buying the video then he/she would be able to pay with any payment gateway.

But in your case the user is paying to use the service to upload videos. So you have to use Google plays billing.

Answer (score 0):

so if user buys a licence key using the app AND that licence key is for use solely for a desktop pc app (not in the app, although the app may be related to the desktop software) then they pay using Paypal?